# UIPanGesture set boundary

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I use UIPanGesture, in the target method, listen to `state`, I set the maximum and minimum values that can be moved;
In the `changed` state, when I detected that the `view.origin.y` of the view exceeded `myOrigin.y`, `view.origin.y = myOrigin.y`. When dragging the view slowly, it doesn't seem to be a problem, but when I drag the view quickly, the view will go beyond this boundary and then immediately become the boundary I set, which looks like it blinks. If I set the animation UIView.animation; it won't blink, but it's obvious that I'm beyond the bounds and return to this action.
I want to know how to avoid this situation.  No matter how fast is dragging, it stops at the boundary I set, and will not exceeded boundary and then return.at least it looks like this

```

```
  let point = pan.translation(in: view)
  switch pan.state {
    case .began:
        break
    case .changed:
        view.frame.origin.y = view.frame.origin.y + point.y
        if view.frame.origin.y > 200{
          view.frame.origin.y = 200
        }
        pan.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
    default ：
    break
  }
```

```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with constraints - which is simpler and more flexible.

This code will create a `100 x 100` blue view in the center of the view controller, allow it to be dragged (via `PanGesture`), and will restrict its vertical movement to 200-pts from the top of the view (and 20-pts from the bottom, so you can't drag it down off the screen).

The key is to use a `centerYAnchor` constraint with a priority of 750 (`.defaultHigh`), along with `>= topAnchor` and `<= bottomAnchor` constraints to limit the vertical positioning.

```
//
//  PanLimitViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 8/1/18.
//

import UIKit

class PanLimitViewController: UIViewController {

    // blue view for panning (dragging)
    var panView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        return v
    }()

    // the panView's center y constraint
    var panCenterYConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    // var to track the current center y
    var currentCenterYConstant: CGFloat = 0.0

    // pan gesture recognizer
    var panGesture  = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add the panView
        view.addSubview(panView)

        // constrain width to 100, height equal to width
        panView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
        panView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: panView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

        // constrain to center horizontally
        panView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        // initialize panView's center y constraint to center of view
        panCenterYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: panView,
            attribute: .centerY,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: view,
            attribute: .centerY,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 0.0)

        // set panView's center y constraint priority to 750
        // required to allow dragging
        panCenterYConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh

        // activate panView's center y constraint
        panCenterYConstraint.isActive = true

        // set panView's topAnchor to >= view's top + 200
        // this will prevent dragging it higher than 200 pts from the top
        panView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 200.0).isActive = true

        // set panView's bottomAnchor to <= view's bottom
        // this will prevent dragging it below the bottom
        panView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true

        // create pan gesture and add to panView
        panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panGestureHandler(_:)))
        panView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

    }

    @objc func panGestureHandler(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began:
            // save the current center y constant value
            currentCenterYConstant = panCenterYConstraint.constant
            break

        case .changed:
            // update panView's center y, based on drag
            let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
            panCenterYConstraint.constant = currentCenterYConstant + translation.y
            break

        case .ended, .cancelled:
            // update panView's center y when drag is finished
            panCenterYConstraint.constant = panView.center.y - view.center.y
            break

        default:
            break
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I want, I see some apis supported by ios9 in the code, I will find out how to write in iOS8.